# Unexpected results using str_split and union in a function with sapply

Tags: r, vectorization, sapply

Given this data.frame:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
ml.mat2 <- structure(list(value = c("a", "b", "c"), ground_truth = c("label1, label3", 
"label2", "label1"), predicted = c("label1", "label2,label3", 
"label1")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

glimpse(ml.mat2)
```

> ```
> Observations: 3
> Variables: 3
> $ value        <chr> "a", "b", "c"
> $ ground_truth <chr> "label1, label3", "label2", "label1"
> $ predicted    <chr> "label1", "label2,label3", "label1"
> ```

I want to measure the length of the intersect between `ground_truth` and `predicted` for each row, after splitting the repeated labels based on `,`.

In other words, I would expect a result of length 3 with values of `2  2  1`.

I wrote a function to do this, but it only seems to work outside of `sapply`:

```
m_fn <- function(x,y) length(union(unlist(sapply(x, str_split,",")), 
                             unlist(sapply(y, str_split,","))))

m_fn(ml.mat2$ground_truth[1], y = ml.mat2$predicted[1])
```

> `[1] 2`

```
m_fn(ml.mat2$ground_truth[2], y = ml.mat2$predicted[2])
```

> `[1] 2`

```
m_fn(ml.mat2$ground_truth[3], y = ml.mat2$predicted[3])
```

> `[1] 1`

Rather than iterating through the rows of the data set manually like this or with a loop, I would expect to be able to vectorize the solution with `sapply` like this:

```
sapply(ml.mat2$ground_truth, m_fn, ml.mat2$predicted)
```

However, the unexpected results are:

> ```
> label1, label3         label2         label1 
>              4              3              3
> ```

Comment: Do you need length of intersect or length of unique

Comment: @Hack-R  You can ccheck the difference `map(ml.mat2[-1], strsplit, ",\\s*") %>% transpose %>% map(reduce, union) %>% lengths` with `map(ml.mat2[-1], strsplit, ",\\s*") %>% transpose %>% map(reduce, intersect) %>% lengths`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're interating within same observation size, you can generate an index of row numbers and run it in your `sapply`:

```
sapply(1:nrow(ml.mat2), function(i) m_fn(x = ml.mat2$ground_truth[i], y = ml.mat2$predicted[i])) 

#[1] 2 2 1
```

or with `seq_len`:

```
sapply(seq_len(nrow(ml.mat2)), function(i) 
  m_fn(x = ml.mat2$ground_truth[i], y = ml.mat2$predicted[i]))
```

Comment: This is great. If possible, can you also please describe what was happening differently in the original attempt?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it seems that `sapply` is returning the length of elements and not the lenght of the intersects. I don't know the reason and it'd be great if someone does.